# Can't use SSL in Rasa Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa

I'm trying to make a Rasa server on Debian AWS to accept posts to port :5005 to parse intents vis JS. I can successfully talk via http://, but not https://

This works:

```
sudo docker run --user 1000 -it -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:2.8.3-full run -- enable-api --cors "*"
```

But this:

```
    sudo docker run --user 1000 -it -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:2.8.3-full run --enable-api --cors "*" --ssl-certificate /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/www.lizasim.com.crt --ssl-keyfile /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/www.lizasim.com.key

Yields errors and I’m pretty sure it’s pointing to the right certs:

 File "/opt/venv/bin/rasa", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/__main__.py", line 117, in main
    cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/run.py", line 95, in run
    rasa.run(**vars(args))
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/api.py", line 57, in run
    rasa.core.run.serve_application(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/run.py", line 189, in serve_application
    ssl_context = server.create_ssl_context(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/server.py", line 435, in create_ssl_context
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(cd
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```